# Get mutiple pictures in one row from other table

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

im making a simpel blogg and i think im having a brain freeze or something...I really cant figure it out how to get this right...
Im having one table called News and one Picture. News can have multiple pictures but a picture can have only one news.

When i do something like:

`SELECT *
    FROM Picture as Pic
    INNER JOIN News as News
    ON Pic.NewsID = News.NewsID
    GROUP BY News.NewsID, News.Header, News.News, News.NewsDate,Pic.Picture`

I want every row with pictures that belongs to a specific News to show on ONE row...
    **Ex: NewsID | Header |News | Picture | Picture | Picture**

```
returns 
NewsID|Header|News|PictureID|Picture
1|myHeader|myNews|1|something.jpg
1|myHeader|myNews|2|othersome.png
2|lolHead|lolNews|3|lol.png
```

and so on...
Please help, regards
/Haris

Comment: I don't think you can do what you are trying to do with a query, get all the results and do it using php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Group concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function

> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL
>   values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

**Example**

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(Pic.Picture) FROM Picture as Pic 
INNER JOIN News as News ON Pic.NewsID = News.NewsID
GROUP BY News.NewsID
```